# In GraphQL how to I query for a random record

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have a Quote type. I'd like to be able to retrieve a random quote. I can get all the quotes using the following query:

```
query {
    allQuotes {
      id
      text
    }
  }
```

How do I get a random record from the Quotes

Comment: I think, you need to create a query whose resolver will fetch and return random query. Or customize this one with parameters somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a good idea in your simplest case to just define `getRandom` resolver on the root-level Query type.

Another approach, given that you say you already have a `Quote` type defined, would be to define a resolver inside it.

Then, for the query from your example, the schema may resemble something like (I didn't test it):

```
type Quote {
  id: Int!
  text: String!
  getRandom(): Quote
}

type Query {
  allQuotes(): [Quote]
}
```

There is also a good example related to randomness in the official docs of GraphQL, try having a look at the [Object Types](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/) section.